# PHP - REGEX get each part of a date into a seperate variable

Tags: php, regex, date

I have a string date like this:

```
$date = "23/12/2011";//format: dd/mm/yyyy.
```

I need each part of this date in its own variable, so that $d=="23", $m=="12", and $y=="2011".

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated...

Comment: Regular expressions: enjoy responsibly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do:

```
list($day, $month, $year) = split("[/]", $yourDate);
```

Comment: `explode()` should be used over `split()` in this case.

Comment: @TimCooper Am I correct in understanding that to mean there is an appreciable performance difference between explode and split? Nevermind, the phpdocs answered that question for me.

Comment: @rdlowrey:  Between `explode()` and `split()`, not `explode()` and `list`.

Comment: ``split()`` is deprecated since it uses the POSIX regex engine, you should avoid it in favour for ``preg_split()`` (RegEx splitting with limited Unicode support), ``mb_split()`` for regex splitting with unicode support or ``explode()`` for regex-less splitting.

Comment: What if you are parsing the following date string "20120924".

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = "23/12/2011";
list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/', $date, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're looking for is `/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/` and in the `preg_match` they would be contained in the $matches array you define in the `preg_match` call.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Backreferences:

```
if (preg_match('%(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})%', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1]; #first two digits are here.. etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this solution, each variable is automatically assigned the proper datatype:

```
sscanf($date, '%d/%d/%d', $d, $m, $y);
```